# Nginx and php-fpm most optimal setup configuration with docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx, fpm

I have a question regarding the most optimal way to set up NGINX and PHP-FPM for my application with docker. So in my set up, my application code and PHP-FPM live in one docker container (the web container), and Ngnix on a separate docker container.

The trick here is that Nginx does not have access to the application files, because they are in the web container, which resulted in some configuration issues with Nginx.
One of those issues is that I can't use the 'root' directive in the Nginx config file, I had to use 'alias' instead. But I managed to get Nginx to point to the proper 'index.php' file in the end (see the config file at the end).

But I was wondering what is the most optimal way to define the relationship between this services?

- Should I just give access to the application code to Nginx?
- Should I set up one more Nginx service in the web container, so that it will accept the requests that come from the Nginx container?
- Or maybe there is some other option that would be even better for my case?

This is my current nginx confg file (I've remove some irrelevant parts):

```
upstream phpserver {
  server web:9000;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name app;
    gzip off;   

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        alias /web/index.php;  

        fastcgi_pass phpserver;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        #include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

        fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

        internal;
        http2_push_preload on;
    }
```